# Could there be a force between the weak and strong forces?

Tags: weak-interaction, strong-force

Could there be a force between the weak and strong forces?

Is possible to *switch* from one force to another or is mandatory to use the Higgs Field as like a monitor/projector of the 4 forces?

The idea of ​​an *channel* between 2 forces mathematically can not do it without passing for the Higgs mechanism?

How the equations have been set today is an exclusive use of high energies, such as GeV or TeV, for a similar idea?

Comment: It is called the electromagnetic force.

Comment: The names of these forces suggest they are similar and can be ordered on some scale, but they can not. It is best to them as two completely independent forces with an unfortunate choice of names. for further info see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_interaction)

Comment: Are you suggesting that to switch from one force to another it is mandatory to use the higgs field ? The idea of ​​an *channel* between 2 forces mathematically can not do it without passing for the higgs mechanism /high energy (TeV) ?

Comment: 1) What do you understand on "switching the forces"? 2) How does Higgs come in this? Higgs relates to the weak interaction. 3) Your last sentence isn't very comprehensible for me, please make it more clear. | I voted to reopen, but I know it won't be enough.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking whether there could be an interaction between the strong and weak interactions.

Well, it isn't entirely clear what that means. There cannot be any (renormalizable) interactions between gluons, which mediate the strong force, and $W$ and $Z$ bosons, which mediate the weak force, because any hypothetical interactions would violate symmetries (Lorentz or gauge) that particles must obey. So in that sense, the force between forces is impossible.

Comment: But instead of being a force the tie could be rather a function that links two different nature forces ? The symmetry of which you will report refers of an invariance, but this invariance is as a sort of constant function Perhaps you should find ways to change the function of this costant function (invariance) without change any mediating force ? You speak about particles 
but the functions and operators that enforce the rules. If function is constant - particle respect the law - but what happens if I change function (constant) of invariance without changing any vector between 2 forces ?

Comment: the same forces should acting differently because what changes is the function of particles not not how they behave but this would mean that the same actions could lead to different consequences even if the particles behave in the same way

Comment: Sorry, you've lost me. Model building is fun, but I suggest you start by carefully learning about what's known already.

Comment: Are you suggesting that to switch from one force to another it is mandatory to use the higgs field ? The idea of ​​an *channel* between 2 forces mathematically can not do it without passing for the higgs mechanism /high energy (TeV) ?